# Error with dependent dropdown in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, drop-down-menu, acrobat

In Acrobat, I want a second "rate" field to populate depending on what is selected in the first "description" field.

I found some code online, but keep getting:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id 2".

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
var DeptData = {
    S00170 Typesetting / Mechanicals: {
        rate: "115.00"
    },
    S00174 Typesetting / Mechanicals: {
        rate: "115.00"
    },
    S00178 File Verification & Creative Digital File: {
        rate: "115.00"
    },
    S00182 Retouching / Image Editing: {
        rate: "125.00"
    },
    S00194 Studio–CGI / Mac Illustration: {
        rate: "125.00"
    }
};

function SetFieldValues(cDescription) {
    this.getField("rate1").value = DeptData[cDescription].rate;
}
```

Comment: Can you place your current code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Sorry, this is all very new to me...but i placed it in JSFiddle and did a "tidyup" and "JSHint", and it stops on line 3 at...   S00170 Typesetting / Mechanicals: {

Comment: You should use `save` and then copy paste the `url` here

Comment: under collaboration it says to use this link:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=lVK8H7R8qL

Comment: // Place all pre-populate data into a single data structure  
var DeptData = {
    S00170 Typesetting / Mechanicals: {
        rate: "115.00"
    },
    S00174 Typesetting / Mechanicals: {
        rate: "115.00"
    },
    S00178 File Verification & Creative Digital File: {
        rate: "115.00"
    },
    S00182 Retouching / Image Editing: {
        rate: "125.00"
    },
    S00194 Studio–CGI / Mac Illustration: {
        rate: "125.00"
    }
};

function SetFieldValues(cDescription) {
    this.getField("rate1").value = DeptData[cDescription].rate;
}

Comment: It is a hunch, but I have the suspicion that the ampersand character in the third entry causes problems; what happens when you take it out? What happens when you escape it?

Answer (score 0):

When defining `DeptData`, putting double quotes around the descriptions should do the trick. The following works for me in the Acrobat console:

```
var DeptData = {
    "S00170 Typesetting / Mechanicals": {
        rate: "115.00"
    },
    "S00174 Typesetting / Mechanicals": {
        rate: "115.00"
    },
    "S00178 File Verification & Creative Digital File": {
        rate: "115.00"
    },
    "S00182 Retouching / Image Editing": {
        rate: "125.00"
    },
    "S00194 Studio–CGI / Mac Illustration": {
        rate: "125.00"
    }
};
```